# Convert a UTF-32 encoded string (C style) in a UTF-16 (JSON style) encoded one in Java/Clojure

Tags: java, json, unicode, encoding, clojure

I am receiving a string from a service that apparently encode its unicode characters using UTF-32 encoding like: `\U0001B000` (C style unicode encoding). However, for serializing this information in JSON, I do have to encode it in UTF-16 like: `\uD82C\uDC00`.

However, I have no idea how I can read such an encoded string in Java/Clojure, and how to produce an output with that other encoded format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the string you want to replace, the following function will do it:

```
(defn escape-utf16
  [[_ _ a b c d]]
  (format "\\u%02X%02X\\u%02X%02X" a b c d))

(defn replace-utf32
  [^String s]
  (let [n (Integer/parseInt (subs s 2) 16)]
    (-> (->> (map #(bit-shift-right n %) [24 16 8 0])
             (map #(bit-and % 0xFF))
             (byte-array))
        (String. "UTF-32")
        (.getBytes "UTF-16")
        (escape-utf16))))

(replace-utf32 "\\U0001B000")
;; => "\\uD82C\\uDC00"
```

And, for targeted replacement, use a regex:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as string])
(string/replace
   "this is a text \\U0001B000."
   #"\\U[0-9A-F]{8}"
   replace-utf32)
;; => "this is a text \\uD82C\\uDC00."
```

Disclaimer: I haven't given a single thought to edge- (or any other than the provided) cases. But I'm sure you can use this as a base for further exploration.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the received bytes from the service using:

```
(slurp received-bytes :encoding "UTF-32")
```

and write a string using:

```
(spit destination string-to-encode :encoding "UTF-16")
```

If you mean that you have a string that represents the binary of the encoded character, then you can convert it using:

```
(defn utf32->str [utf32-str]
  (let [buf (java.nio.ByteBuffer/allocate 4)]
    (.putInt buf (Integer/parseInt (subs  utf32-str 2) 16))
    (String. (.array buf) "UTF-32")))

(utf32->str "\\U0001B000" )
```

and then convert it to UTF-16 using:

```
(defn str->utf16 [s]
  (let [byte->str #(format "%02x" %)]
    (apply str
           (drop 1 (map #(str "\\U" (byte->str (first %) ) (byte->str (second %) ))
                        (partition 2 (.getBytes s "UTF-16")))))))
```

Here is a sample run:

```
(str->utf16 (utf32->str "\\U0001B000"))
;=> "\\Ud82c\\Udc00"
```

Comment: It doesn't really work the way I was intending. I tried `(spit "resources/unicode.output" (slurp "resources/unicode.input" :encoding "UTF-32") :encode "UTF-16")` but it doesn't produce the JSON/UTF-16 encoding I mentioned in my question. Also note that what I put in the `unicode.input` file is the string `\U0001B000` and what I get back with `slurp` is 3 bytes: `0xFFFD 0xFFFD 0xFFFD`

Comment: Are you sure your unicode.input is in UTF-32 encoding? `(spit "out.txt" (slurp  "in.txt" :encoding "UTF-32") :encoding "UTF-16")` with in.txt `0000000: 0000 feff 0001 b000 0000 000a` and out.txt `0000000: feff d82c dc00 000a` as the output from running `xxd`.

Comment: @Neoasimov Notice that on the call to `spit` you wrote `:encode` instead of `:enconding`.

Comment: @Symfrog, @juan-facorro: thanks for your inputs! Yes that would work, but maybe I was not clear with my question. What I am looking for is to consume UTF-32 written in C like representation `\U0001B000` and then to write it back in JSON like representation UTF-16: `\uD82C\uDC00`. Is this `slurp` call really supposed to do that? If so, I still have something wrong.

Comment: @Neoasimov Could you provide a minimal sample of your resources/unicode.input run through xxd, i.e. `xxd resources/unicode.input `?

Comment: @Symfrog sure, as simple as: `"this is a test \U0001B000 this is a test"`. What I am looking for is to produce this string: `"this is a test \uD82C\uDC00 this is a test"`. Not sure if we can do that with Clojure/Java core APIs, or if there exists some libraries to do that kind of work.

Comment: @Neoasimov I have updated the answer to take into account  your example.

Comment: @Symfrog wonderful! Clean, simple and working great. Exactly what I was looking for. I was lacking much to get to this point :)

Comment: While this solution surely achieves its goal, there is a lot of overhead in there: the creation of a `ByteBuffer`, `ByteOutputStream`, as well as imperative-style `slurp`/`spit` operations. Regarding performance, it probably won't do well compared to more data-oriented/functional ones.